# Fileupload control unable to upload .swf file in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, upload, controls

I am working on a project, in which I need to upload the .swf file by using ASP.Net fileupload control. But, when I click upload button, it doesn't work even not arises any related error, but "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" this error arise which is not related to by problem. While, instead of .swf file, when I tried to upload .doc, .txt, it uploads without any error.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means your swf file is too big. Try to increase the maximimum allowed upload size in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
It works perfectly. Everytime I got the solution on my problem. I never return back with empty hands. Therefore, I said "BRILLIENT EXPERIENCE BRAINS" are on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

How large is the file?  You might be exceeding the max size that you have configured.
Have you tried it in any other browsers to see if you get a better error message?

Comment: Thank you sir. I got my solution.
<system.web> 
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" /> 
</system.web>